# small touchscreen for handheld instrument

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm trying to find a small approx 2.5" touchscreen display that would be good for utilization in a small battery powered handheld instrument that has a frequently updating value that it reads.  e-ink/e-paper displays are low power but have refresh rate issues.  Other types of screens I'm finding use too much power to run off of a 9 volt for more than a day.

Comment: I suggest that you share a list displays you have found in the body of the questions. Also what are your electrical and product requirements be side need use 9V.

Comment: Search on here, this has been asked before especially about e-ink displays...

Comment: I did search but couldn't locate.  At the moment, I'm looking at this display.  It's not e-ink/e-paper but does appear to have a low power usage.  New Haven C12865
http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-C12865AR-FSW-GBW.pdf

Comment: Trying to put it into a case that is 4.63 x 2.84 x 1.00 in. exterior.  It's a tight fit but the New Haven display would fit.  The New Haven display doesn't come as a touchscreen and I don't have the experience of trying to add one.  I'd prefer to locate a more ready to go solution.